# wkhmltopdf and div on two pages

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf

I created pdf with Symfony by helping me with KnpSnappyBundle which uses wkhtmltopdf.

In one of my pdf files, I have a column on the left and one on the right. I would like the two columns to finish at the bottom of the page, so I put a style css "height: 100%".

This works fine if the pdf only makes one page, but if the contents of one of the columns overflow on another page, the divs are not extended to the second page.

[image]

So I would like that if the content goes beyond the first page, the two columns finish at the bottom of the second page.

Here is the current code of my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <style>

        #colonneGauche {
            width: 25%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #4c5667;
            float: left;
        }

        #content {
            width: 75%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #bacbe1;
            float: left;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="colonneGauche">

    <p>lorem</p>

</div>

<div id="content">

    <p>ipsum</p>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

I tested the css "page-break-after: avoid;" but it did not work.

If one of you has an idea...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Equal height columns is the default behaviour for Bootstrap 4 grids.  Are you using a version of Bootstrap?

Comment: @kerrin yes, I using bootstrap v3.3.2

Comment: How does it go if you follow something like this?  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp

Comment: @kerrin same problem ... it's like the property "height: 100%" working only for the first page, I can't do this if the pdf have two pages.